# How do I manage end-of-call behaviour in Mobile Safari when page is bookmarked to desktop?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, mobile-safari, tel

I have a HTML5 mobile web app that needs to provide links so that the user can make phone calls. Adding the link to make the phone call is easy:

```
<a href="tel:+15556345789">Call me</a>
```

However, managing the post call behaviour is not.

If I view the app inside Mobile Safari, and click on the link, I get taken to the Phone app to make the call. When the call ends, the iPhone returns to Mobile Safari, on the same page I was on previously (i.e., the page that initiated the call).

However, if I bookmark the same page to the desktop (so the user experience is closer to an "app"), and click on the same link, I am directed to the phone desktop at the completion of the call. This means I need to reload the mobile "app", and navigate back to where I was when I made the call.

Why is the behaviour different between the two? Is there any way to get the bookmarked app to return to the same context that initiated the call?

Answer (score 0):

Just a complete guess, but what if the link is to a page that redirects to the "tel:" URL?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `target = _blank`? Just a blind guess. :-)